# F# Dictionary Builder from List/Seq

Tags: dictionary, f#

Is there a constructor for Dictionary in F# (that takes a Seq/List as input, and output a Dictionary)? I have written the following code that does what I want, but I am just curious maybe it is already implemented (and so I don't need to implement it myself)

```
let DictionaryBuilder (keyFunc:'a->'b) (valueFunc:'a->'c) aList =
    let dict = new Dictionary<'b,'c>()
    aList 
    |> Seq.iter (fun a -> dict.Add(keyFunc a, valueFunc a ))
    dict    // return
```

I know that in C#, you can use .ToDictionary (using System.Linq)

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.Linq;
List<string> example = new List<string> {"a","b","c"};
Dictionary<string,string> output = example.ToDictionary(x => x+"Key", x => x+"Value");
// Output: {"aKey": "aValue", "bKey": "bValue", "cKey": "cValue"}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The signature of the dict function it's as follows:

```
dict : seq<'Key * 'Value> -> IDictionary<'Key,'Value>
```

So it takes a key value sequence as input. The key here would be to give it a key value sequence. In your case, you could use map instead of iter. The lines of code will be similar but it's a more functional way.

```
aList 
|> Seq.map (fun a -> keyFunc a, valueFunc a )
|> dict
```

**Edit**

As TheQuickBrownFox have noted in the comments, the dict function produces a read-only dictionary.

Comment: Watch out for the fact that `dict` produces a read only dictionary (it will throw an exception when you try to add or remove items). You can get around this by passing that dictionary again to the Dictionary constructor: `... |> dict |> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you just use LINQ:

```
open System.Linq
[1; 2; 3].ToDictionary(id, (*) 2)
```

Either use it directly or use it in your helper function if you'd rather use a function than an extension method.

```
module Seq =
    open System.Linq
    let toDictionary (f:'s -> 'k) (g:'s -> 'v) (xs:_ seq) = xs.ToDictionary(f, g)
```